# Lock Portrait mode in hybrid mobile app

Tags: javascript, html, autorotate, portrait

Hey guys I need to lock my screen orientation of my hybrid mobile app using `HTML` or `JS`

I tried `Screen.lockOrientation()' Function from MDN  but the program just hung up.

Any other simple way to do this using `JS` or `JQ`  or ' CSS'?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no. You cannot lock the orientation from a website. Only Mozilla support the javascript function you provided (from version 18 and upwards).

You should do this by using a native extension or plugin for your mobile app.